# Spring boot Data source config with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, datasource

For now I am fetching the Datasource properties from the application properties file in spring boot. I want to fetch the data source properties from the DS.xml file placed at the external location on the tomcat 7 server. I want this to be a JNDI based configuration. I am using the JPA repository so it possible to do this with minimum changes to the code.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can do, but you need to run the application as below command:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<external-config-file> myBootProject.jar
```

please refer the bwlow url for details:
[externalise guide URL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

> You can always use JNDI to configure your data-source with an
>   application server (like tomcat, weblogic) and then within your app
>   fetch that data-source and use it.

*Some application servers like weblogic provides you a way to config it with GUI and some don't*